# Automatically calling dev.off after plot in R

Tags: r, rlang

I'm looking for a way to automatically call dev.off() to flush a plot to disk when someone calls plot() or ggplot().

Is this possible? RStudio looks to automatically load the plot, how does that work?

Comment: To address the second part: RStudio creates its own graphics device, of type `RStudioGD`. If you right-click and "inspect" a plot in RStudio, you'll see that the image is a temporary file, sent to RStudio (which is essentially a browser) by a server running behind the scenes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**  Add possible approach for `ggplot`.

Note that the *reason* that `plot`, in particular, doesn't automatically call `dev.off()` is that it's very common -- after calling `plot` -- to add additional material (annotations, supplementary plotting features, titles, legends, etc.) with additional calls before calling `dev.off()` to finalize the output.

But, if you *really* want `plot` to finalize the plot and prevent any further content from being added, you can do it by redefining `plot`:

```
plot <- function(...) {
    graphics::plot(...)
    dev.off()
}
```

Note that for window-based graphics devices (e.g., `x11`), the plot will briefly flash on the screen before disappearing, since `dev.off()` closes the window, but it should work fine for files:

```
> png("plot.png")
> plot(1:10,runif(10))
null device     <-- proof that dev.off() was called
          1 
>
```

For `ggplot2`, I guess your best bet is to override the `print` method (which is how a plot normally gets displayed on the screen).  So, if you define:

```
print.ggplot <- function(...) {
    ggplot2:::print.ggplot(...)
    dev.off()
}
```

then:

```
> png("plot.png")
> ggplot(mapping=aes(x=1:10,y=1:10))+geom_line()
[[ print method is implicitly called here ]]
> dev.off()   # to prove that dev.off() was already called
Error in dev.off() : cannel shut down device 1 (the null device)
>
```

appears to work the way you want.

I don't use RStudio, so I'm not sure what it's doing differently, but I'm going to guess that it intercepts the graphics commands in such a way that it simultaneously shows the "plot in progress" before the file is finalized, rather than actually displaying the file (which, for bitmapped graphics, can't be written out at all until the plot is completely finished and `dev.off()` is called).

Comment: Probably better to give the function a name other than `plot()` lest it create some unintended craziness downstream.

Comment: Thank you! How would you solve this for ggplot and other graphs? I tried but it appears to cause an error.

Comment: Can you provide a real-world `ggplot` example of how you'd like this to work?

Comment: library('ggplot2')
ggplot(mapping=aes(x=1:10, y=1:10)) + geom_line()

Comment: Okay, but where should this output go?  What device was open that now needs to be closed?  Wouldn't it be easier to use `ggsave` to save the last plot than assume a device was open and `dev.off()` it?